# How to give priority to dropdown option list so that useful for sorting the database?

Tags: sql

HTML code where I have put values in number to get easily sort out through query

```
difficulty level:
<select name="difficult1" id="difficult1">
    <option value="">level</option>
    <option value="3">easy</option>
    <option value="2">moderate</option>
    <option value="1">difficult</option>
</select>
```

SQL query where I want to sort the data according to difficulty level wise as per number given

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY deadline ASC , difficulty ASC";
```

Ok. Now the problem is according to value defined in dropdown. Database is storing the values as per number but not the names used in dropdown. So how to give priority to the dropdown list options so that I can sort also and store the actual names too? Please help. I'm working on live project. its must for me. Thanks in advnce.

Comment: What would be your desired result?

Comment: i want letters mentioned in mu dropdown... but database is showing 1,2,3 number in the difficulty feild as i hav used numbers in 'values'

Comment: can you give the database table structure? It is unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ruffp id | task | difficulty level                                                                        ------>                                                                       1  |  create web | moderate

Comment: @ruffp id | task | difficulty level                                                                        ------>                                                                       1  |  create web | moderate                                                                    ---------------> so this would be my table and there will be number of tasks here.. and i want to sort it on the basis of difficulty level options... given in html code....

Comment: @usernu but it looks another table than your `user` table. When I ask the db structure is: make an update (edit) of your question and describe all table (only the used ones) that you use from your DB, it includes the user table because it is the one you mention in your query.